# How do I implement a password Reset Link

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, password-recovery

I currently have a system where if a user has forgotten their password, they can reset it by clicking on a forgot password link. They will be taken to a page where they enter in their username/email and then an email will be sent to the user, I wanted to know how can I implement a password reset link in the email so once the user clicks on the link he/she is taken to a page which will allow them to reset their password.

This is the code in my controller

```
public ActionResult ForgotPassword()
        {
           //verify user id

            string UserId = Request.Params ["txtUserName"];
            string msg = "";
            if (UserId == null) 
            {
                msg = "You Have Entered An Invalid UserId - Try Again";
                ViewData["ForgotPassword"] = msg;
                return View("ForgotPassword");
            }

            SqlConnection lsql = null;
            lsql = DBFactory.GetInstance().getMyConnection();

            String sqlstring = "SELECT * from dbo.[USERS] where USERID = '" + UserId.ToString() + "'";
            SqlCommand myCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlstring, lsql);
            lsql.Open();
            Boolean validUser;         
            using (SqlDataReader myReader = myCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {

                validUser = false;
                while (myReader.Read())
                {
                    validUser = true;

                }
                myReader.Close();
            }
            myCommand.Dispose();  


            if (!validUser) 
                  {
                msg = "You Have Entered An Invalid UserId - Try Again";
                ViewData["ForgotPassword"] = msg;
                lsql.Close();
                return View("ForgotPassword");
            }

            //run store procedure


            using (lsql)
            {
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Stock_Check_Test.dbo.RESET_PASSWORD", lsql);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter paramUsername = new SqlParameter("@var1", UserId);

                cmd.Parameters.Add(paramUsername);


                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (rdr.Read())
                {
                    if (Convert.ToInt32(rdr["RC"]) == 99)
                    {
                        msg = "Unable to update password at this time";
                        ViewData["ForgotPassword"] = msg;
                        lsql.Close();
                        return View("ForgotPassword");  

                    }
                }
            }


            msg = "new password sent";
            ViewData["ForgotPassword"] = msg;
            lsql.Close();
            return View("ForgotPassword");
        }
```

This is my current stored procedure which sends the user an email

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[A_SEND_MAIL]
    @var1 varchar (200), -- userid
    @var2 varchar (200) -- email address
AS
BEGIN
declare @bodytext varchar(200);
set @bodytext = 'Password Reset for user: ' +@var1 + ' @' + cast (getDate() as varchar) + ' ' ;
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
@profile_name='Test',
@recipients=@var2,
@subject='Password Reset',
@body=@bodytext
END 

GO
```

Comment: You generate a long random string and store it alongside the userid (and an expiry date), navigate to reset.aspx?id=longstring and use it to identify the user and display a reset page, deleting/invalidating the string on success.

Comment: You need to parameterize ALL your queries. The first query in here is wide open to sql injection. Also, you really should specify only the columns you need instead of using *.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Create a table that has a structure like

```
create table ResetTickets(
    username varchar(200),
    tokenHash varbinary(16),
    expirationDate datetime,
    tokenUsed bit)
```

Then in your code when the user clicks the reset password button you will generate a random token then put a entry in that table with the hashed value of that `token` and a expiration date of something like `DATEADD(day, 1, GETDATE())` and appends that token value on the url you email to the user for the password reset page.

```
www.example.com/passwordReset?username=Karan&token=ZB71yObR
```

On the password reset page you take the username and token passed in, hash the token again then compare that with the `ResetTickets` table, and if the expiration date has not passed yet and the token has not been used yet then take the user to a page that lets them enter a new password.

**Things to be careful about**:

1. **Make sure to expire the token**, don't let a email from two years ago reset the password.
2. **Make sure to mark the token as used**, don't let other users of the computer use the browser's history to reset other users passwords.
3. **Make sure you generate the random token safely**. Don't use `Rand` and use it to generate the token, two users who reset at the same time would get the same token (I could reset my password and your password at the same time then use my token to reset your account). Instead make a static [`RNGCryptoServiceProvider`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider(v=vs.110).aspx) and use the `GetBytes` method from that, the class is thread safe so you don't need to worry about two threads using the same instance.
4. **Be sure to [parameterize your queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7505808/using-parameters-in-sql-statements).** In your current code if I typed in the userid `'; delete dbo.[USERS] --` it would delete all the users in your database. See the linked SO post for more info on how to fix it.
5. **Be sure you hash the token, your `passwordReset` page only accepts the unhashed version, and you never store the unhashed version anywhere** (including email logs of outgoing messages to users). This prevents an attacker who has read access to the database from making a token for some other user, reading the value that was sent in the email, then sending the same value himself (and perhaps getting access to an administrator user who can do more stuff than just read values).

Comment: One more thing, store only a **hash** of the token, an attacker with read access to the db (SQL-injection) could otherwise reset any account he wishes.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain if only hash is stored in DB how could one compare the random token coming from email with the original token generated? I am asking this in assumption that "hashed values are not possible to reverse hash"

Comment: @Athul You generate the random token, email that token. Hash the token and save it in the DB. When the link is clicked you hash the token that was passed in to the reset link using the same hash method as when you stored it in to the database. You then you check if the stored hash matches the hash you just generated. This is the same process you do when you check if a password is correct, you never compare passwords, you only check if two hashes of passwords are the same value.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain what about if I use a JWT token instead? do you think it is necessary to hash it as well?

Comment: I know this is old but.. is it really necessary to pass the user to the reset endpoint? Shouldn't the token be enough?

Answer (score 1):

here are 2 alternatives using HMAC or JWT (which i think provide better, more secure, email URLS)

- https://neosmart.net/blog/2015/using-hmac-signatures-to-avoid-database-writes/
- https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/11/safe-password-resets-with-json-web-tokens/